# How do I update the slide master from Slideshow Mode and refresh current slide using VBA?

Tags: vba, microsoft-powerpoint

I'm trying to have a counter in all slides of a powerpoint presentation.
The counter needs be controlled a button in all slides that increases it.

I can do it for one specific slide, but when I do it with a slide master it doesn't refresh the screen during Slideshow mode. I have to exit slideshow and enter again to see the changes.

Code that doesn't refresh in Slideshow mode:

```
ctr = ctr + 1
ActivePresentation.Designs(1).SlideMaster.Shapes("Counter").TextFrame2.TextRange.Text = ctr
```

Code that works (but only applies to one slide, not all slides in presentation):

```
ctr = ctr + 1
ActivePresentation.Slides(1).Shapes("Counter").TextFrame2.TextRange.Text = ctr
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

What about just inserting **‹Nr.›** into your textbox without VBA.
This will update automatically.

Or just click on **SlideNumber** in the Insert tab of your menu bar while your cursor is in your textbox

Comment: (1) ‘‘The counter needs be controlled [by] a button’’ — apparently the OP does not want something that updates automatically. (2) ‘‘from Slideshow Mode’’ — the menu bar isn't accessible in Slideshow Mode.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue. I don't know of to do but here is a workaround below. This will quickly open slide and then go back to the slideshow forcing it to update.

```
Sub ForceScreenUpdate()
Dim lSlideIndex As Long
lSlideIndex = SlideShowWindows(1).View.CurrentShowPosition
ActivePresentation.SlideShowWindow.View.Exit
ActivePresentation.SlideShowSettings.Run
SlideShowWindows(1).View.GotoSlide lSlideIndex
End Sub
```